# Can't create directory named "mysql" in subversion repository

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, forbidden

I have a particular problem with subversion.

Environment: subversion (1.6.12dfsg-6), apache2 (2.2.16-6+squeeze7) + mod dav_svn.

I can't create a directory named "mysql" or "testmysql" or add and commit a file named "mysql.txt" in my repository.

There are many references to "subversion PROPSET 403 forbidden" problems in google and so on.

But I can use all functions of subversion. I can also create a directory named "hugo" or "test". My repository works properly.

Only "mysql" doesn't work.

The following errors occur:

```
The server encountered an unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to the 
request for MKCOL »/svn/repository/!svn/wrk/8123484e-8890-412d-92ed-62ceabcd4189
/etc/mysql" returned
```

/var/log/apache2/access.log

```
192.168.178.200 - - [time] "OPTIONS /svn/repository/etc HTTP/1.1" 401 6156 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "OPTIONS /svn/repository/etc HTTP/1.1" 200 1028 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "MKACTIVITY /svn/repository/!svn/act/6564e2e2-19be-4a09-bcb6-61a1cfb097e8 HTTP/1.1" 201 676 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/etc HTTP/1.1" 207 676 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "CHECKOUT /svn/repository/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 201 692 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "PROPPATCH /svn/repository/!svn/wbl/6564e2e2-19be-4a09-bcb6-61a1cfb097e8/157 HTTP/1.1" 207 580 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "PROPFIND /svn/repository/etc HTTP/1.1" 207 564 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "CHECKOUT /svn/repository/!svn/ver/157/etc HTTP/1.1" 201 692 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "MKCOL /svn/repository/!svn/wrk/6564e2e2-19be-4a09-bcb6-61a1cfb097e8/etc/mysql HTTP/1.1" 403 596 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.178.200 - user1 [time] "DELETE /svn/repository/!svn/act/6564e2e2-19be-4a09-bcb6-61a1cfb097e8 HTTP/1.1" 204 165 "-" "SVN/1.6.12 (r955767) neon/0.29.3"
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have something in your apache config that is refusing such URLs with "mysql" in them. Have you looked thoroughly through your configuration? Try grep for "mysql" in there.

Comment: What a stupid mistake. `RewriteRule mysql - [NC,F,L]`. I thought I had corrected all theses files. Thank you.